# How to handle render error in Vue that returns an undefined error

Tags: if-statement, vuejs2, conditional-statements

I have the code below that throws an undefined error on run, is there anyway I can trap or use a conditional formatting to it? Here's what I've done so far:

```
<data-list 
    label='Group Name: '
    :change="gotoGroups()"
></data-list> //this a search and select drop-down list
```

**METHOD:**

```
gotoGroups(){
    if(this.$refs['groupName'].choice != 'undefined'){
    //I have also tried (typeof this.$refs['groupName'].choice != 'undefined')
    //do this
    }
}
```

Warning fired:

> app.js:22462 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'choice' of undefined"

Both of them is not working, how can I surpass it?

Comment: I badly need help here :( Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of this `TypeError`. Use the code as follows

```
if(this.$refs['groupName'] && this.$refs['groupName'].choice != 'undefined'){   
  //do this
}
```

To know more about `Short-circuit evaluation` you can have a look at this [resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description)

Comment: Thanks for this but this will throw an infinite loop :S

Comment: @ramedju I cannot see any loop here, can you please clarify your statement?

Comment: Please see my update. It's more detailed. It's called on load.

Comment: Actually you are getting `undefined` value for `this.$refs['groupName']` and trying to find a value of key `choice` of this `undefined` array member.

Comment: Thanks for this, this still has helped me a bit :)